# Is it possible to call C functions from within LLVM JIT-compiled functions?

Tags: c, llvm, jit

I'm trying to call one or more precompiled C functions from within one or more LLVM JIT-compiled functions. (When I say "precompiled" here, I just mean that the function is in my source files, and that it's getting compiled when I type "make".) As I understand it, the C++ way to do this is using `llvm::ExecutionEngine::addGlobalMapping`. I don't currently know C++, so it would be really helpful if this were possible within plain old C. Does anyone know if it is? I'm currently using gcc, but would be happy to switch to clang or anything else if that solves the problem. Everything ChatGPT gives me just segfaults and/or really just doesn't have a hope of working, for what it's worth.

**Remark.** I'm interested not only in answers of the form "yes this is possible", but also in answers of the form "no this is not".